# Empty attributes with distributed indexes

Tags: search, sphinx, pecl

When i search in distributed index i have empty attributes

```
[matches] => Array
    (
        [9] => Array
            (
                [weight] => 1
                [attrs] => Array
                    (
                    )

            )

        [28] => Array
            (
                [weight] => 1
                [attrs] => Array
                    (
                    )

            )
```

My sphinx.conf

```
#!/usr/local/bin/php

source base_src
{
    type = xmlpipe2
}

<?php for($i=1;$i<=6;$i++): ?>
source main_src_<?php echo $i; ?> : base_src
{
    xmlpipe_command     = /usr/local/bin/php /home/yanovskiy/project/indexer.php --main <?php echo ($i - 1); ?>
}
<?php endfor; ?>

index base_index
{
    docinfo         = extern
    mlock           = 1
    morphology      = none
    min_word_len        = 3
    charset_type        = utf-8
    enable_star     = 0
    html_strip      = 0
}

<?php for($i=1;$i<=6;$i++): ?>
index main_index_<?php echo $i; ?> : base_index
{
    source              = main_src_<?php echo $i; ?>
    path                = /var/db/sphinxsearch/data/main_<?php echo $i; ?>

}
<?php endfor; ?>

index dist
{
    type                = distributed
    <?php for($i=1;$i<=6;$i++): ?>
    local               = main_index_<?php echo $i; ?>
    <?php endfor; ?>
}
```

I have the same schemas in all indexes. I checked it with *indextool --dumpheader* and manually.

When I search in *main_index_1* or *main_index_2* separately then all is well, but if i search in *dist* index - attributes are empty. Can anybody help me with this?

I use Sphinx 2.1.2-release on FreeBSD 9.2

Comment: I'm not alone with this problem
http://sphinxsearch.com/bugs/view.php?id=1532

Comment: I created new issue in bugtracker
http://sphinxsearch.com/bugs/view.php?id=1760

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem in PHP extension from PECL (Version 1.3.0)

Comment: Is there some fix? I have the same problem :-(

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem here until we upgraded to the latest release of Sphinx server (2.2.10)